Mining is on more than 10% of the questions, how can we structure that content better?
Mining is a central topic to Bitcoin, yet we lump everything even remotely related to it into one tag, mining. Tags lose a lot of their usefulness when they are applied to too many questions.
Therefore I would like to suggest that we deprecate the usage of mining altogether (perhaps by eventually blacklisting it as we have done with bitcoin), and replace it with a number of other tags.

This topic aims to collect tags that should replace mining on questions. Such tags can be new or already exist.
Please propose one tag per answer, and add support by describing what topic it would collect. Please upvote answers that you find useful, and downvote tags that you don’t. Use comments on answers to discuss viability or edit the answers directly to improve them.
Once we have concluded this discussion, another post will follow to suggest how to implement it and what to watch for while retagging mining.

related: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/575/5406

mining-hardware 
Collects questions about mining rigs, cpus, gpus, fpgas, and asicminers, as well as the production, and producers of such.

My concern is that people will use this tag for all mining questions, sorta like people use bitcoind as a surrogate for the restricted bitcoin tag.

@NickODell Do you have a suggestion how we can alleviate it? Else I would say, we should just stick to it, and then finetune once we see the issues.

miner-configuration
Collects questions about configuration of mining hardware, and optimizing the software settings of mining rigs.

@fredsbend: Good point. If we have enough questions for both topics yes. If they are too few, they should be merged, I think.

pool-payout-methods
Questions about sharing revenue in mining pools.

gpu-mining
Questions about using GPUs for mining. 
Although mostly of historical use, gpu collects 112 questions, but essentially only collects questions about using gpus for mining. 

cpu-mining
Questions about using CPUs for mining.
Although mostly of historical use, cpu collects 63 questions, but essentially only collects questions about using CPUs for mining. 

I think this should be used for the plethora of 'mining just for fun' questions.

Finally, any tag that collects questions about a specific mining hardware product or producer, e.g. antminer, bitmain, or butterfly-labs, which can be applied to at least five (better ten) questions.

shares
Shares refers to a method for accounting mining pool contributions. It does not cover company shares.

mining-concept mining-theory
Questions about the function, the reason for, and the underlying concepts of mining.
Closely related to proof-of-work.

Not happy with this tag yet, I’d welcome a better suggestion.

mining-profitability
Collects questions about the economics of mining operations.

Apply to: Any questions that currently have both mining and profitability, and other questions closely related.

This tag seems a bit too specific. We need like one question with this tag, and that's how to calculate profitability from energy cost, hashrate, and difficulty. This seems like it would be used for 'if I mine with this hardware, will I make money?' questions, which we should probably close as being time sensitive.

Yeah, we probably could do with about five. Yet, we do have 46 questions on that topic. ;) And having them all on one tag might help us get fewer new ones. :)

mining-pools
Questions about organizing groups to collaboratively work on block creation.

When people think of a tag, 'pool' or 'pools' probably comes to mind before 'mining-pools'. So, I would opt for 'pool-mining', just to have 'pool' be first in the tag name. A similar argument could probably be made for other proposed tags here as well.

I’m not sure I follow. When I type "pool" in the tags box, mining-pools shows up as the first choice.

I knew I should have double checked to see if SE is smart enough to search tag by contains rather than startswith. 'mining-pools' sounds good to me then.

@fredsbend: I'm just re-reading this. How would you distinguishbetween mining-pools and pooled-mining? [tag:solo-mining] exists and is in use.

@fredsbend: Yeah, questions asking about specific pools could easily have specific tags, but then I'd not see how to cleanly separate pooled-mining and mining-pools thereafter. I'd expect that the bulk of the question would be tagged with both. Maybe if one got rid of tag mining-pools altogether, and replaced it with pooled-mining, pool-payout-methods, pool-work-distribution, and a few more.

@fredsbend: I just rediscovered your answer on a related topic, where you argued that mining-pools and pooled-mining should be merged. Just thought it was funny. :)

scrypt-mining
Questions specific to mining any altcoin using the Scrypt hash algorithm.

I don't like this one because it opens the door for many more tags, e.g. X11-mining, Keccak-mining, etc. If their question is about mining, the algorithm usually isn't the focus. If the algorithm is the focus, it probably doesn't belong on this SE, since we're not dedicated to knowing the ins-and-outs of hash functions.

@StephenM347 Hm. If we just create only tags that would be on at least 10 questions, Scrypt should be the only one. However, at the moment we have more than 200 questions that have "scrypt" in the text and are tagged with [tag:mining]. You are right though, they may not be a collection of a consistent topic.
